# visual studios 2012 problems configuring x64 compiler

Tags: visual-studio-2012, 64-bit, cplex

I'm trying to use **CPLEX** with **Visual Studio 2012** and I have to configure VS to compile 64bit applications. I downloaded the entire software from dreamspark.com so I'm almost sure I got the compiler installed. However, when I'm trying to follow the [step by step instructions from microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/9yb4317s.aspx), I can't go further than step 5 because I don't have the option 64-bit plateform in the drop-down list.

I tried to write x64 and follow the other instructions but I get errors when I'm building. When I take a look at the log, I guess it may be a conflict between VS 2010 and VS 2012, but before I installed VS12, I god rid of VS2010 (maybe I forgot something? I erased the environnement variables and uninstalled the softwares) Anyway, here is the log:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: ConsoleApplication1 (Visual Studio 2010), Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>Build started 2013-05-30 11:20:28.
1>Building with tools version "4.0".
1>Target "_CheckForInvalidConfigurationAndPlatform" in file "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.Targets" from project "C:\Users\Fred\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1.vcxproj" (entry point):
1>Task "Error" skipped, due to false condition; ( '$(_InvalidConfigurationError)' == 'true' ) was evaluated as ( '' == 'true' ).
1>Task "Warning" skipped, due to false condition; ( '$(_InvalidConfigurationWarning)' == 'true' ) was evaluated as ( '' == 'true' ).
1>Using "Message" task from assembly "Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v4.0, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".
1>Task "Message"
1>  Configuration=Debug
1>Done executing task "Message".
1>Task "Message"
1>  Platform=x64
1>Done executing task "Message".
1>Task "Error" skipped, due to false condition; ('$(OutDir)' != '' and !HasTrailingSlash('$(OutDir)')) was evaluated as ('C:\Users\Fred\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\x64\Debug\' != '' and !HasTrailingSlash('C:\Users\Fred\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\x64\Debug\')).
1>Task "Error" skipped, due to false condition; ('$(BaseIntermediateOutputPath)' != '' and !HasTrailingSlash('$(BaseIntermediateOutputPath)')) was evaluated as ('obj\' != '' and !HasTrailingSlash('obj\')).
1>Task "Error" skipped, due to false condition; ('$(IntermediateOutputPath)' != '' and !HasTrailingSlash('$(IntermediateOutputPath)')) was evaluated as ('x64\Debug\' != '' and !HasTrailingSlash('x64\Debug\')).
1>Done building target "_CheckForInvalidConfigurationAndPlatform" in project "ConsoleApplication1.vcxproj".
1>Target "_PrepareForBuild" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.BuildSteps.Targets" from project "C:\Users\Fred\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1.vcxproj" (target "Build" depends on it):
1>Task "CreateItem" skipped, due to false condition; ('%(CustomBuild.IncludeFileToTool)'!='') was evaluated as (''!='').
1>Done building target "_PrepareForBuild" in project "ConsoleApplication1.vcxproj".
1>Target "_PrepareForReferenceResolution" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets" from project "C:\Users\Fred\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1.vcxproj" (target "ResolveReferences" depends on it):
1>Task "Message" skipped, due to false condition; ('$(_REFERENCE_DEBUG)'=='true') was evaluated as (''=='true').
1>Done building target "_PrepareForReferenceResolution" in project "ConsoleApplication1.vcxproj".
1>Target "ComputeCrtSDKReference" skipped, due to false condition; ('@(ClCompile)'!='' and '$(WindowsAppContainer)'=='true' and '$(UseCrtSDKReference)' != 'false') was evaluated as ('ConsoleApplication1.cpp;stdafx.cpp'!='' and ''=='true' and '' != 'false').
1>Target "BeforeResolveReferences" in file "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.Targets" from project "C:\Users\Fred\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1.vcxproj" (target "ResolveReferences" depends on it):
1>Done building target "BeforeResolveReferences" in project "ConsoleApplication1.vcxproj".
1>Target "AssignProjectConfiguration" in file "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.Targets" from project "C:\Users\Fred\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1.vcxproj" (target "ResolveReferences" depends on it):
1>Using "AssignProjectConfiguration" task from assembly "Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v4.0, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".
1>Task "AssignProjectConfiguration"
1>Done executing task "AssignProjectConfiguration".
1>Done building target "AssignProjectConfiguration" in project "ConsoleApplication1.vcxproj".
1>Target "AssignProjectConfiguration" skipped. Previously built successfully.
1>Target "_SplitProjectReferencesByFileExistence" in file "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.Targets" from project "C:\Users\Fred\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1.vcxproj" (target "ResolveProjectReferences" depends on it):
1>Task "ResolveNonMSBuildProjectOutput" skipped, due to false condition; ('$(BuildingInsideVisualStudio)'=='true' and '@(ProjectReferenceWithConfiguration)'!='') was evaluated as ('true'=='true' and ''!='').
1>Done building target "_SplitProjectReferencesByFileExistence" in project "ConsoleApplication1.vcxproj".
1>Target "_RemoveNameMetadataFromProjectReferenceItems" skipped, due to false condition; ('@(ProjectReference)'!='') was evaluated as (''!='').
1>Target "ResolveProjectReferences" in file "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.Targets" from project "C:\Users\Fred\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1.vcxproj" (target "ResolveReferences" depends on it):
1>Task "MSBuild" skipped, due to false condition; ('%(_MSBuildProjectReferenceExistent.BuildReference)' == 'true' and '@(ProjectReferenceWithConfiguration)' != '' and ('$(BuildingInsideVisualStudio)' == 'true' or '$(BuildProjectReferences)' != 'true') and '@(_MSBuildProjectReferenceExistent)' != '') was evaluated as ('' == 'true' and '' != '' and ('true' == 'true' or 'true' != 'true') and '' != '').
1>Task "MSBuild" skipped, due to false condition; ('%(_MSBuildProjectReferenceExistent.BuildReference)' == 'true' and '@(ProjectReferenceWithConfiguration)' != '' and '$(BuildingInsideVisualStudio)' != 'true' and '$(BuildProjectReferences)' == 'true' and '@(_MSBuildProjectReferenceExistent)' != '') was evaluated as ('' == 'true' and '' != '' and 'true' != 'true' and 'true' == 'true' and '' != '').
1>Task "MSBuild" skipped, due to false condition; ('%(_MSBuildProjectReferenceExistent.BuildReference)' == 'true' and '@(ProjectReferenceWithConfiguration)' != '' and '$(BuildingProject)' == 'true' and '@(_MSBuildProjectReferenceExistent)' != '') was evaluated as ('' == 'true' and '' != '' and 'true' == 'true' and '' != '').
1>Task "Warning" skipped, due to false condition; ('@(ProjectReferenceWithConfiguration)' != '' and '@(_MSBuildProjectReferenceNonexistent)' != '') was evaluated as ('' != '' and '' != '').
1>Done building target "ResolveProjectReferences" in project "ConsoleApplication1.vcxproj".
1>Target "ResolveNativeReferences" skipped, due to false condition; ('@(NativeReference)'!='') was evaluated as (''!='').
1>Target "_PrepareForReferenceResolution" skipped. Previously built successfully.
1>Target "GetFrameworkPaths" in file "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.NETFramework.targets" from project "C:\Users\Fred\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1.vcxproj" (target "ResolveAssemblyReferences" depends on it):
1>Done building target "GetFrameworkPaths" in project "ConsoleApplication1.vcxproj".
1>Target "GetWinFXPath" skipped, due to false condition; (('@(Page)' != '' or '@(ApplicationDefinition)' != '' or '@(Resource)' != '') and ('$(GetWinFXNativePath)' != '' or '$(GetWinFXWoWPath)' != '' )) was evaluated as (('' != '' or '' != '' or '' != '') and ('' != '' or '' != '' )).
1>Target "GetReferenceAssemblyPaths" in file "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.Targets" from project "C:\Users\Fred\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1.vcxproj" (target "ResolveAssemblyReferences" depends on it):
1>Task "GetReferenceAssemblyPaths" skipped, due to false condition; ('$(TargetFrameworkMoniker)' != '' and ('$(_TargetFrameworkDirectories)' == '' or '$(_FullFrameworkReferenceAssemblyPaths)' == '')) was evaluated as ('' != '' and ('C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0' == '' or 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0' == '')).
1>Done building target "GetReferenceAssemblyPaths" in project "ConsoleApplication1.vcxproj".
1>Target "SetBuildDefaultEnvironmentVariables" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.Cpp.targets" from project "C:\Users\Fred\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1.vcxproj" (target "PrepareForBuild" depends on it):
1>Using "SetEnv" task from assembly "Microsoft.Build.CppTasks.Common.v110, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".
1>Task "SetEnv"
1>  PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\bin\x86_amd64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\bin\x86;;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\Tools\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\tools;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\ide;C:\Program Files (x86)\HTML Help Workshop;C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\;;C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application;C:\Program Files (x86)\insightful\splus80\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Lenovo;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Ulead Systems\MPEG;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Lenovo;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\SWTOOLS\ReadyApps;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Services\IPT\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Symantec\VIP Access Client\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Lenovo\Access Connections\;C:\Users\Fred\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\tools;C:\Users\Fred\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools;C:\MinGW\Bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\HP\Digital Imaging\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\HP\Digital Imaging\bin\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2011a\runtime\win64;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2011a\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Python27;C:\Users\Fred\Desktop\apache-ant-1.8.4-bin\apache-ant-1.8.4\bin\ant.bat;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\bin\java.exe;C:\Users\Fred\Desktop\apache-ant-1.8.4-bin\apache-ant-1.8.4\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\doxygen\bin;C\Program Files (x86)\CMake 2.6\bin;C:\wxWidgets-2.8.12;C:\Qt\4.8.4\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Graphviz2.30\bin;C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio125\opl\bin\x64_win64;C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio125\opl\oplide\;C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio125\cplex\bin\x64_win64;C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio125\cpoptimizer\bin\x64_win64;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake 2.6\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake 2.6\bin;
1>Done executing task "SetEnv".
1>Task "SetEnv" skipped, due to false condition; ('$(_IsNativeEnvironment)' == 'true') was evaluated as ('' == 'true').
1>Task "SetEnv"
1>  LIB=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\lib\amd64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\atlmfc\lib\amd64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\lib\win8\um\x64;;
1>Done executing task "SetEnv".
1>Task "SetEnv"
1>  LIBPATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\atlmfc\lib\amd64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\lib\amd64;
1>Done executing task "SetEnv".
1>Task "SetEnv"
1>  INCLUDE=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\atlmfc\include;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\um;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\winrt;;
1>Done executing task "SetEnv".
1>Done building target "SetBuildDefaultEnvironmentVariables" in project "ConsoleApplication1.vcxproj".
1>Target "SetUserMacroEnvironmentVariables" skipped, due to false condition; ('@(BuildMacro)' != '') was evaluated as ('' != '').
1>Target "GetResolvedWinMD" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets" from project "C:\Users\Fred\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1.vcxproj" (target "PrepareForBuild" depends on it):
1>Done building target "GetResolvedWinMD" in project "ConsoleApplication1.vcxproj".
1>Target "PlatformPrepareForBuild" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.Cpp.Platform.targets" from project "C:\Users\Fred\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1.vcxproj" (target "PrepareForBuild" depends on it):
1>Task "VCMessage" skipped, due to false condition; ('$(DesignTimeBuild)'!='true' and '$(ConfigurationPlatformExists)' != 'true') was evaluated as (''!='true' and 'true' != 'true').
1>Using "VCMessage" task from assembly "Microsoft.Build.CppTasks.Common.v110, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".
1>Task "VCMessage"
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.Cpp.Platform.targets(42,5): error MSB8020: The builds tools for Visual Studio 2010 (Platform Toolset = 'v100') cannot be found. To build using the v100 build tools, either click the Project menu or right-click the solution, and then select "Update VC++ Projects...". Install Visual Studio 2010 to build using the Visual Studio 2010 build tools.
1>Done executing task "VCMessage" -- FAILED.
1>Done building target "PlatformPrepareForBuild" in project "ConsoleApplication1.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
1>
1>Build FAILED.
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:00:00.04
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this would solve your problem but when you uninstalled VS2010, it might have removed Platform SDK v100 but you still reference it in your project.  Go to `Properties --> Configuration Properties --> General --> Platform Toolset` and select `v110` instead.